# Drupal json output bad format

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-modules

Need some help please, 
Actually, I am using Drupal 8 as a content manager for my mobile application. 
For that, I need to output my contents as JSON structures, meanwhile, I am using address and office hours modules in my data. 
The problem is that when I try to output my data, I get some "\n" and spaces in the response like show the images : 
[image]

I need a result like that :

```
address:{ "address": "", "city" : "" ,"zip_code": "", "country":{}}
```

[image]

```
"openingHours":[{"day":"Saturday","opening":"07:00", "closing":"18:00"},{"day":"Sunday","opening":"10:00", "closing":"18:00"}]
```

Any Idea to how to rewrite the response to get a proper data? 
for information, the problem appears only when I use fields. 
thank you

Comment: What is the "proper data" format you want? \n is generally how newline characters are represented in JSON, so the output you have is what is to be expected. You do not mention what version of Drupal, how you are outputting the JSON (drupal core module? custom module?) or what language you are using in your app to consume the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I am using Drupal 8, for the format, I need a separate information {field_address_campus : { address : "" , city:" " , zip code: " "} for the address and separate days for office hours.

Comment: And I am developing mobile app for both Android and IOS so JAVA and SWIFT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the address on mobile you need to replace \n with space or the character which mobile developer use for the linebreak.

Comment: Yeah, that's clear, but I prefer output proper data rather than handling that on my mobile side code.